# How to add id to a block

Tags: 7, blocks

For example I have the code:

```
function contact_block_view($delta = '') {
$block = array();
switch ($delta) {
  case 'contact_block':
  $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('contact_form');
break;  
}
return $block; 
}
```

How to set inside this block the id or class attributes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will not be able to add an `id` or class `attribute` to the block in your [`hook_block_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) implementation. At this stage you are not yet dealing with the markup of the block itself but only the markup for its content. In order to set the `id` or `class` of the block markup, you will need to use [`hook_preprocess_block()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7) or [`hook_process_block()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_process_HOOK/7) to add a usable variables to the [`block.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) template. Then you will need to actually use the variables in the template itself.

Fortunately, the default `block.tpl.php` file already provides variables for both the `id`  and `class` attributes of your block (`$block_html_id` and `$classes`). Actually, [`template_preprocess_block`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7) already sets the id to `'block-' . $variables['block']->module . '-' . $variables['block']->delta`. So in your case, using the default template, your block will have `block-contact-contact-block` as `id`. But it can be changed if needed. In any preprocessor functions, you can add and remove CSS classes by manipulating `$classes_array` variables. Both are illustrated in the following code.

```
function MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block']->module == 'contact' && $variables['block']->delta == 'contact_block') {
    $variables['block_html_id'] = drupal_html_id('your-id-here');
    $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('your-class-here');
  }
}
```